# return a list in a method that is referencing a PD Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to return a list or tuple when referencing a pandas DF? get_df() is a pandas column with a couple hundred float values. The code below is asking to return the values greater than 6000 and less than 7000. Can I return a list to my method? (I know I can print this but that is not what I am trying to do)

```
def mass_needed(numb_one, numb_two):
    for i in get_df():
        if i > numb_one and i < numb_two:
            return(i)
print(mass_needed(6000, 7000))
```

What I am trying to accomplish is I want to be able to call mass_needed() and get a list values that I can print or manipulate just like a normal list.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish? It helps if you provide an example

Comment: Why a list, why not a `Series`?

Comment: Isn't a series and a list basically the same thing.

Comment: What does basically mean?  Series has a lot more info than a list.

Comment: `df.col[df.col.between(numb_one, numb_two, inclusive=False)]` you can turn this into a list if you want to.

Comment: @bnicholl no, not really. I mean, they are both sequences, but `Series` offer all the indexing magic that you use `pandas` for.

Comment: @AChampion Nice! Never knew about `.between` but that's more efficient than what I would typically use!

Comment: Yea, I guess I just thought of a series as a list with index's. And it seems as though I really shouldn't use a for loop to try and return a large list or series? Thats really what I was trying to figure out. Was if I could return the list using the above method.

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone cared, I figured it out. Had to append the the values as they were being iterated through.

```
def mass_needed(numb_one, numb_two):
    li = []
    for i in get_df():
        if i > numb_one and i < numb_two:
            li.append(i)
    return li        


x = pd.DataFrame(mass_needed(6000, 7000))
print(x)
```